# How to save date as Timestamp in firestore using firebase-admin?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, timestamp

Trying to convert from javascript date to firestore timestamp throws

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'Timestamp' of undefined
```

I tried it in 2 ways:

1. Using firebase-admin

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const db = admin.firestore();
const timestamp = db.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date(date));
```

2. Using firebase.firestore:

```
const firebase = require('firebase');
const timestamp = firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date(date));
```

**date** used as a param in **new Date** is of this format: "2017-01-29".

**Expected result**: firestore timestamp.

**Actual result**: TypeError: Cannot read property 'Timestamp' of undefined

**Note**: db nor firebase are null or undefined.

Is there a definitive way of creating firestore timestamp from javascript date object?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your second example isn't using the Firebase Admin SDK at all - that's the Firebase web client SDK.

If you're working with the Admin SDK prior to v11:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const timestamp = admin.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(...)
```

Or v11:

```
const { Timestamp } = require('firebase-admin/firestore')
const timestamp = Timestamp.fromDate(...)
```

Comment: I changed my first option to admin.firstore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date(date)) and it is working.

Comment: This one is working on deployed cloud functions, is there a way to make it work when I test my cloud functions locally? It returns TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'fromDate')

Comment: Question: when did this change exactly (i.e. what verion ?)... Are the two following equivalent?   1. `import { Timestamp } from 'firebase-admin/firestore';` / 2.  `import { Timestamp } from '@google-cloud/firestore';`

Answer (score 6):

The accepted answer doesn't work in the latest version of firebase-admin (v11). admin.firestore.Timestamp is undefined. Here is how I got it working in the new version:

```js
const { Timestamp } = require('firebase-admin/firestore')
const timestamp = Timestamp.fromDate(new Date(...))
```

Answer (score -3):

Import

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
```

and use

```
created_at = firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp();
```

Comment: This is irrelevant for Firebase Admin Sdk.